Irreducible Polynomial $p$ is separable iff $p'\neq 0$
I am teaching myself algebra using a lecture notes, which has the following statement
Let $K$ be a field and $p\in K[x]$ be irreducible. Then $p$ is separable if and only if $p'\neq 0$.
I have troubles with the "only if" direction. I know that if $p'\neq 0$ then $p$ and $p'$ must be relatively prime, implying that $p$ is separable. However, if we assume that $p$ is separable, then how do we prove that $p'$ is non-zero? The lecture notes does not seem to explain this.

The common roots of $p$ and $p'$ (in the algebraic closure) are the multiple roots of $p$. Since $p$ is separable, it has no multiple roots, so $p'$ is not zero at the roots of $p$, and hence it is not identically zero.

@tomasz Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information.

@Runyang Please use the search feature. For example, see the OP's proof in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957209, or the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141012, etc.
